# iOS Controls coordinates

Tags: ios, uiview, frame

Is it possible to find out right or bottom coordinate of some child control inside some UIView?
One way of doing this for rightmost x coordinate of control is by adding control's `frame.size.width` + `frame.origin.x`.

I think I've read somewhere that this value is available as property, not sure where, maybe in some framework..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame)`,`CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame)`

to get the right-bottom co-ordinate, you could also use Core Graphics methods like

```
CGRectGetMinX and CGRectGetMinY .. etc
```